# Files don't by fs.writeFile() on Heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku, fs

JSON-files don't write by `fs.writeFile` on Heroku.
Console is clear.

```
fs.writeFile('${__dirname}/config.json', JSON.stringify(config),(err) => {
     if(err) console.log(err);
});
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can't persistently write files to Heroku's filesystem, which [is ephemeral](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#ephemeral-filesystem). Any changes you make will be lost the next time your dyno restart, which [happens frequently](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#automatic-dyno-restarts) (at least once per day).

Use a client-server database like [PostgreSQL](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql) (or choose [another service](https://elements.heroku.com/addons/#data-stores)), or store files on a third-party object storage service [like Amazon S3 instead](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/s3).

Answer (score 0):

Two suggestions:

1. Try using "writeFileSync" function instead of "writeFile"
2. Make a function and include your line in the body.  Add "await" to the first line.  Then put "async" at the front.  Then call the function.  For example:

```js
const myWriteFunction = async (filename) => {
  await fs.writeFile(filename, 'Hello World')
}
```

Comment: One other thing, Heroku apparently has a temporary filesystem.  See https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#ephemeral-filesystem